# UIImagePickerController cameraOverlayView not working with iPhone 5?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, iphone-5, camera-overlay

When iPhone 5 came out, my custom cameraOverlay no longer lined up to cover the default camera shutter and cancel button.

I added some code to detect the phone's hardware version and moved the controls down a bit for iPhone 5.

Well, now those custom buttons no longer receive the tap events, rather they fall through to the camera's buttons. Why?

For an experiment control, I used the same code to relocate the buttons on iPhone 4S (they are both running iOS 6). So, the two attached pictures are using the same exact code with the difference of a constant number (pixel offset).

On the 4s, my custom buttons receive tap events. On the 5, the tap events fall though to the camera's controls. Is this a bug? It certainly seems like it. I was hoping that someone else has run into the same problem.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with my buttons not receiving events, and it was fixed by selecting "Full screen at launch" on the MainWindow.xib.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually figured this out. It had to do with how/when the ViewController and the UIImagePickerController were being created and intialized. I recoded the entry/exit points to the class and it now works well.

Comment: Could you elaborate further on this? I'm having the same problem - responsive Camera Overlay UI on all iPhones except iPhone 5

Comment: @HCHogan It would be helpful to others (such as @ShaiMishali) if you write up how you solved the problem as an answer and accept your own answer. Thanks!

Comment: @HCHogan : Can you please provide a code. I am running thought same problem but even in iPhone4, button at the bottom works if it is called through viewDidLoad but NOT if called after wards like viewWillAppear or thought any other button action ! 
cameraSwapButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, deviceHeight-45, 50, 35);
this will work if y =  deviceHeight-90